# How can I detect sprite collisions out of screen?

Tags: java, android, sprites, game-mechanics, andengine

I am creating an *Android game* using *andEngine* library.

I have enemies coming from out of the screen into the screen. I already know how to detect collisions, but is there any **method** I can use to detect when my enemies (*sprites*) collide with another sprite **before** entering the screen? The sprites I want to detect the collision with are on the corners of the screen.